# Lookup two Display Names using the same Table on 1 unique assignment in SQL Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2012, ms-project-server-2013

I am trying to write a query where two different UIDs need to lookup a Resource Name for both, but separately.

In other words, for each Task, there are resources assigned and one status manager.  This converts in SQl to an Assignment, unique to a resource, but with the same status manager. However, no where in the database can one see the Status Manager's Name on a given assignment.

The assignment does have "TaskStatusManagerUID" available.  The name of the Status Manager can be determined by tying it back to MSP_EPMResource table where TaskStatusManagerUID = ResourceUID.

The catch is, for my report, I need to be able to look at the ResourceUID *and* TaskstatusManagerUID and determine the names of each on the same assignment.

While I have been successful with a join to display the name for one or the other, I have not been able to determine how to show the name for both the Resource and TaskStatusManager.

This is an example of what I am trying to display (parentheses added for readability):

(AssignmentUID) (Task Name) (Resource Name) (Task Status Manager Name)

See more info below:

[image]

This is the code I have been working with, but have been unsuccessful:

```
Select top 100
c.[assignmentuid], 
a.[taskname], 
c.[resourceuid],
b.[resourcename], 
a.[taskstatusmanageruid],
d.[StatusManager]

from [PRJPROD_ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[MSP_EpmAssignment] c
join [PRJPROD_ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[MSP_EpmTask_UserView] a
on a.[TaskUID] = c.[TaskUID]
join [PRJPROD_ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[MSP_EpmResource] b
on b.[ResourceUID] = c.[ResourceUID]

join (select b.resourcename StatusManager
from [PRJPROD_ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[MSP_EpmResource] b) d 
on d.[StatusManager] = a.[taskstatusmanageruid] 

group by 
c.[assignmentuid], 
a.[taskname], 
c.[resourceuid],
b.[resourcename], 
a.[taskstatusmanageruid],
d.[StatusManager]
```

Currently, I am getting "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your joins you have `on a.[TaskUID] = c.[TaskUID]`, `on b.[ResourceUID] = c.[ResourceUID]`, and `on d.[StatusManager] = a.[taskstatusmanageruid]`, of which, I am assuming that the last one is causing you the issue. Try instead

```
join (select b.resourcename StatusManager
from [PRJPROD_ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[MSP_EpmResource] b) d 
on d.[StatusManager] = CONVERT(CHAR, a.[taskstatusmanageruid])
```

This will convert the GUID contained in `taskstatusmanageruid` to a char string, allowing it to compare successfully.

You could also, instead of converting the value, cast the value `CAST(a.[taskstatusmanageruid] AS CHAR`

**EDIT**

Due to the nature of the GUID, you may not be able to convert/cast it to a char value, in which case you would need to convert/cast both fields to either varchar or nvarchar:

```
join (select b.resourcename StatusManager
from [PRJPROD_ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[MSP_EpmResource] b) d 
on CONVERT([N]VARCHAR, d.[StatusManager]) = CONVERT([N]VARCHAR, a.[taskstatusmanageruid])
```

OR

```
join (select b.resourcename StatusManager
from [PRJPROD_ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[MSP_EpmResource] b) d 
on CAST(d.[StatusManager] AS [N]VARCHAR) = CAST( a.[taskstatusmanageruid] AS [N]VARCHAR)
```

Comment: Good catch, but it still isn't working.  Now it is telling me "Insufficient result space to convert uniqueidentifier value to char."  with both the Convert and Cast.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Instead of converting/casting to char, convert/cast both values to varchar or nvarchar, I will edit answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jeff Beese's extra set of eyes, it was enough for me to get the last piece in place!

```
Select top 100
c.[assignmentuid], 
a.[taskname], 
c.[resourceuid],
b.[resourcename], 
a.[taskstatusmanageruid],
d.[StatusManager]

from [PRJPROD_ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[MSP_EpmAssignment] c
join [PRJPROD_ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[MSP_EpmTask_UserView] a
on a.[TaskUID] = c.[TaskUID]
join [PRJPROD_ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[MSP_EpmResource] b
on b.[ResourceUID] = c.[ResourceUID]

join (select b.resourcename as StatusManager, 
             b.ResourceUID 
from [PRJPROD_ProjectWebApp].[dbo].[MSP_EpmResource] b) d 
on d.[resourceuid] = a.[taskstatusmanageruid]


group by 
c.[assignmentuid], 
a.[taskname], 
c.[resourceuid],
b.[resourcename], 
a.[taskstatusmanageruid],
d.[StatusManager]
```